# UIButton in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I want to some part of the text in UIButton as Bold and other and other part of it as plain. Also I want to put bolded text in one line and the plain text in the other. Can we accomplish with UIButton in Swift out of the box. Or should we make a custom cell/view that fits my need.

Comment: @rmaddy This is not a duplicate. In addition, to multiple lines, I 'm also asking about applying different fonts/ styling to different pieces of text. So, kindly remove the mis-leading duplicate tag.

Comment: If you read through the Swift answers in the duplicate, it shows how to apply different fonts to different parts of the multi-line label.

Comment: That doesn't mean the question is duplicate.

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate? Both your question and the other ask the same thing - how to create a button with two lines of text each using a different font. Same question. The answers in the other provide solutions to both questions. Please explain why you don't think it's a duplicate. And it's not bad to mark your question a duplicate. It helps other people find an answer. It's a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here is an example playground.  Note you need to set an attributed title and enable word wrapping or it won't work.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let button = UIButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Line 1\n", attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)])
        text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Line 2", attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .regular)]))
        button.setAttributedTitle(text, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        button.sizeToFit()
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```